# What is InCallService(Android) equivalent in iOS

Tags: android, ios, telephony, callkit, dtmf

In Android, they have this new API called InCallService where you can get call events and for each call object you can do some action. I'm looking for equivalent in iOS. In iOS, I wanted to do the achieve the same thing specifically for outgoing call also. In iOS there is CXCallObserverDelegate protocol but in this case I can only get UUID of the call that's all I can get. I'm not able to do any additional action for the call. I wanted to execute DTMF tone once the call is active but it is not possible. In CallKit there is cxaction called CXPlayDTMFCallAction but this only applies for VOIP application and what I need is to execute the dtmf for gsm calls. Does anybody have any solution for here?

Comment: You can't do what your want on iOS.

Comment: so did you try it before? and you didn't succeed also? so there's no work around for this ?

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but as your own research has found there is no way to interact with calls that aren't managed by your own voip app. There are much stricter privacy and security restrictions on iOS than in Android

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Even in Android they are strict because this InCallService just release for Marshmallow and developer needs to fully developed a custom dialer and change the default dialer just to use this service which is not necessary in my case.

Comment: Are you initiating the outgoing call from app or any call from native dialer also?

Comment: I'm initiating the call from the app using the tel scheme. Do you have solution?

Comment: In iOS 12.1, in Contacts App, when searching for particular contact, in the results I see section “Top Matches” with this contact’s full name (from my list) and then additional section “Siri Found in Apps” with just First and Last Name (no prefix, middle initial, or suffix). When I click on that latter result, it opens a screen similar to that when you open an entry in Call History (“Recents”), where the the same compact name is shown as title and below:
“phone (Siri found in InCallService)
+1 (123) 456-7890” Google on com.apple.inCallService to see more leads.